# how can get the property from result of jwt.verify() method that was already created

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jwt

In my node.js project, I have used typescript.

I want to get `userId` from the result of `jwt.verify()` but I got an error.

How can I fix this problem?
(If I don't use typescript, there is no problem.)

**userService.ts file:**

In Login method I have the following code:

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"; 

// I have defined userId
token = jwt.sign({ userId: userId, email: email }, secretKey, { expiresIn: expiresIn });
```

**check-auth.ts file:**

Also in check-auth middleware I have:

```
 import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";


 const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);

 // Property 'userId' does not exist on type 'string | object'.
 // Property 'userId' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

 req.userData = { userId: decodedToken.userId }; // I need to access to the userId
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is `jwt.verify` doesn't know what might be inside encoded `token` string. In fact there may be anything signed with the right key. So you must hint TS about the expected type. As the most quick solution:

```ts
type MyToken = {
  userId: string
  email: string
  iat: number
  exp: number
}

const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY) as MyToken;

req.userData = { userId: decodedToken.userId }; // ok
```

Though for production code I'd use something like [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) to verify contents of the decoded token:

```ts
type MyToken = {
  userId: string
  email: string
  iat: number
  exp: number
}

const decodedToken: unknown = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);

function verifyDecodedToken(data: unknown): asserts data is MyToken {
  if (!(data instanceof Object)) 
    throw new Error('Decoded token error. Token must be an object');
  if (!('userId' in data)) 
    throw new Error('Decoded token error. Missing required field "userId"');

  // other necessary checks
}

verifyDecodedToken(decodedToken);

req.userData = { userId: decodedToken.userId }; // ok
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJ92Dm)

Answer (score -1):

Replace

> import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

with

> import * as jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

```
// example,
import * as jwt from "jsonwebtoken"; 
let secretKey = "test";
let token = jwt.sign({ userId: "test", email: "test@test.com" },secretKey,{ expiresIn: 300000 });
const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, secretKey);
let result = { userId: decodedToken.userId }; // I need to access to the userId
console.log(result);
```